# javascript, parseInt behavior when passing in a float number

Tags: javascript, parseint

I have the following two parseInt() and I am not quite sure why they gave me different results:

`alert(parseInt(0.00001))` shows 0;

`alert(parseInt(0.00000001))` shows 1

My guess is that since parseInt needs string parameter, it treats `0.00001` as `""+0.00001` which is `"0.00001"`, therefore, the first alert will show `0` after parseInt. For the second statement, `""+0.00000001` will be `"1e-8"`, whose parseInt will be `1`. Am I correct?

Thanks

Comment: Always add a radix, `parseInt(0.00001, 10)`

Comment: Your question is confusing. You first said that the first alert shows `0.00001`, but then you said it shows `0`. It shows `0` for me.

Comment: Seems like you're on the right track:  `String(0.00000001)` --> "1e-8" and `parseInt("1e-8");` -> 1

Comment: Barmar: you are right, the first alert shows 0. Sorry about that

Comment: Over and over I see people incorrectly using `parseInt` (a _string parsing function_) as a means to round a number.  This shows exactly why you shouldn't do it!

Comment: @Alnitak:I am not trying to use parseInt to round a number. I was reading JQuery Types documentation and noticed parseInt( 0.000001) returns 1 and I did not understand. That is why I tried to use different values to figure out why. But thanks for pointing this out so others will be aware.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I believe you are correct.

```
parseInt(0.00001) == parseInt(String(0.00001)) == parseInt('0.00001') ==> 0

parseInt(0.00000001) == parseInt(String(0.00000001)) == parseInt('1e-8') ==> 1
```

Comment: Thanks for confirming!

Comment: Note that `0.00000001.toFixed(8)` returns the correct string

Comment: A question in which the hypothesis is already correctly given doesn't need answers, it just needs comments confirming the hypothesis and closing.

Answer (score 0):

`parseInt` takes each character in the first argument (converted to a string) that it recognizes as a number, and as soon as it finds a non-numeric value it ignores that value and the rest of the string. (see [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/parseInt) second paragraph under "Description")

Therefore it's likely that `parseInt(0.00000001)` === `parseInt(String(0.00000001))` === `parseInt("1e-8")`, which would only extract the 1 from the string yielding `parseInt("1")` === `1`

However, there's another possibility:

From Mozilla developer network:
parseInt(string, radix);

for the string argument (emphasis added): "The value to parse. If string is not a string, then it is converted to **one**. Leading whitespace in the string is ignored."

I think this possibility is less likely, since String(0.00000001) does not yield NAN.

Answer (score 0):

You are correct.

parseInt is intended to get a number from a string.  So, if you pass it a number, it first converts it into a string, and then back into a number.  After string conversion, parseInt starts at the first number in the string and gives up at the first non-number related character.  So "1.e-8" becomes "1"

If you know you are starting with a string, and are just trying to get an Integer value, you can do something like.

```
Math.round(Number('0.00000001')); // 0
```

If you know you have a floating point number and not a string...

```
Math.round(0.00000001); // 0
```

You can also truncate, ceil(), or floor the number